# Can't open keyboard on Android, while modal appears

Tags: react-native

I have a `Modal` and a `TextInput` inside this modal, I want that keyboard be open, when modal appears, however, keyboard appears only in `IOS`.

TextInput is focused, however, keyboard appears only once user taps on TextInput.

Here is my code:

```
export default class MyModal extends React.Component { 

    componentDidMount() {
        this.ref.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return  (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Modal
                    animationType="slide"
                    transparent
                    visible={true}
                    onRequestClose={() => {}}>
                    <View style={styles.modalViewStyle}>
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}> 
                         <TextInput
                            ref={ref => this.ref = ref}
                            autoFocus={true}
                            value={this.props.reflection}
                            onChange={ e => this.props.onChange('reflection', e) }
                        />  
                        </View>
                        </View>    
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your Modal appear from the bottom of the screen ? If so then there could be a possibility that the Keyboard did appear, but it's hidden behind the Modal. 
If that is the case,then based on Keyboard's event functions `keyboardDidShow, keyboardDidHide` (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard#docsNav ) push your Modal up (marginBottom : Keyboard Height ).
Hope this helps.